# How to detect when a templated UserControl is removed from UI (not just hidden in UI)

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate, itemscontrol

I have an `ItemsControl` with its `ItemsSource` bound to an `ObservableCollection<T>`, using my own `UserControl` as the `ItemTemplate`:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyObservableColletion, Mode=OneWay}">

  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <MyControls:MyUserControl />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

</ItemsControl>
```

I've got it hooked up so that the UI is updated as items are added/removed to/from the collection.

**When an item is removed from the collection, I want to detect this in the code-behind of the representative templated `MyUserControl`. How can I do this?**

I did notice that the `Unloaded` event fires in this case, but it's not adequate for my purpose because `Unloaded` also fires when the UI containing my `ItemsControl` is simply hidden/collapsed (e.g. when it's in a `TabControl` and the tab is switched away).

Is there another event for this purpose, or a way of detecting in the body of an `Unloaded` handler that my control is definitely removed and not just hidden?

Comment: Where is your `MyObservableCollection` is this bound to using a viewmodel? and `Mode=OnWay` has to be `Mode=OneWay`

Comment: This app does not use MVVM so there is no viewmodel – MyObservableCollection is in the code-behind of the control which contains the ItemsControl. My XAML example code above is slightly simplified - in reality I use a RelativeSource to hook up the binding. (Also I fixed typo - thanks.)

Comment: You could use the events on the ObservableCollection i think. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx `CollectionChanged and PropertyChanged` events

Comment: Good idea, but the code i want to execute when the control is removed references UI properties (it's basically a clean-up operation - detaching events, etc.). So handling via the ObservableCollection's events won't suffice.

Comment: But your usercontrol also have events that will fire depending on what state transition is happening right? Unloaded event or something

Comment: Yes the Unloaded event fires. But Unloaded also fires in other situations (as described in question) in which I would definitely not want to execute my clean-up code, which makes it an unreliable detector.

Comment: I have a potential solution which scales the control's ancestors in the VisualTree in the Unloaded event handler. When the control is unloaded by hiding it, the entire tree is still there. When the control is unloaded by removing it, it only seems to have a single ContentPresenter parent. I'll do more tests with this approach and see if it's reliable. Still hoping there's a simpler solution though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102005/discussion-between-jordy-van-eijk-and-ross).

Comment: @Ross Have you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

since your your "MyObservableColletion" should be of type ObservableCollection you should be able to subscribe to it's "CollectionChanged" event. Its EventHandler will trigger on adding and removing. In the event args you will find The oldItems array that will contain the collection that was removed from the collection.

```
public void CollectionChangedEventHandler(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
    var deletedItem = args.OldItems.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

in WPF you do not deal with controls in code. never ever. You play with the data that is represented by controls.

Comment: Jordy van Eijk suggested this in a comment to the original question, but it won't suffice. I need to detect the user control being removed so I can detach UI events, etc. Doing this in the OC's CollectionChanged event would be irrelevant/impossible, as that event deals with data only.

Comment: "In WPF you do not deal with controls in code. never ever." Sometimes you do, like in my case when detaching a UI event.

Comment: WHAAAAAAAAT ? you should not need to do that. As the control is disposed the invocation lists of the eventhandlers will be as well. I would say your cleanup code has a wrong concept. After I learned to work with WPF properly, I almost never needed to work with controls in code.

Comment: MAAAAAYBE. But while "re-architect your whole solution" might be a sufficient long-term answer to a problem like this, sometimes a short-term answer is needed (e.g. to fix a bug in a complicated shipped product, which is what I'm doing).

Comment: "short term solutions" tend to become "long term bugs"

Comment: what is your clean up procedure doing. what ever it is it can be done in the eventhandler

Answer (score 0):

We need to check if any property is changed for the dis-connected `UserControl`. One such property is `DataContext`, as after `UserControl` is not in the `ItemsControl`, so it's `DataContext` will be reset. And for dis-connected controls, it is set to `{DisconnectedItem}`.

Add this code in your `UserControl`.

```
protected override void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Property.Name == "DataContext" && e.NewValue.ToString() == "{DisconnectedItem}")
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(this + " : I am removed !");
    }
    base.OnPropertyChanged(e);
}
```